# Add branding bar in wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, branding

I am a web developer since in HTML I was using some html code that allows user to see interactive branding in the HTML. I'm not sure if it is possible with `wxPython`, But I had seen a software with this kind of branding. But it was made in `JavaFx`
Brandin I expect is Something like this(in HTML Code) :

```
   <div id="branding" role="banner">
        <div class="topbar">
            <h1><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Brand Name"></a></h1>
            <h2 id="site-description">company brand name </h2>
    </div>
```

and manipulating it with CSS to show the interactive branding.

My Questions are -

- Can I create the branding in wxPython just before the toolbar?
- I wanted to display logos of client on left corner and our organisation's brand on right top corner.  And the Brand name in the center. Is it possible to implement?

Right now I have just created a login page.

```
 import wx 
 class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    """"""
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.showLoginBox()

    def showLoginBox(self):
        """
        """
        # Create the sizer
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=9, cols=2, hgap=5, vgap=15)

        # Username
        self.txt_Username = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1, size=(150, -1))
        lbl_Username = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Username:")
        sizer.Add(lbl_Username,0, wx.LEFT|wx.TOP| wx.RIGHT, 50)
        sizer.Add(self.txt_Username,0, wx.TOP| wx.RIGHT, 50)

        # Password
        self.txt_Password = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1, size=(150, -1), style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        lbl_Password = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Password:")
        sizer.Add(lbl_Password,0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 50)
        sizer.Add(self.txt_Password,0, wx.RIGHT, 50)

        # Submit button
        btn_Process = wx.Button(self, -1, "&Login")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSubmit, btn_Process)
        sizer.Add(btn_Process,0, wx.LEFT, 50)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Comment: not sure what the login page has to do with your question?  If you want it before the ToolBar you will have to manage the ToolBar yourself in a sizer instead of letting the wx.Frame do that.  Haven't done this but you could probably use HTML2_Webview for the branding then have the toolbar and then the rest of your UI.

Comment: @Werner:- Let me try that. Thanks for reply.